# how to get an url into a div using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a dynamic div which gets the text from a Jquery function, some like this:

```
if(value.length == '') {
    error_text = 'This is not correct, please <a href="http://domain.com">contact us.</a>';
    $("#div_error").text(error_text);
}
```

In the div I get "This is not correct, please <"a href="http://domain.com">contact us.".

I put an " after the < so Stackoverflow wouldn't make it a hyperlink as I want it to be .... ;-)

It seems OK but what I really want offcourse is that it would be "This is not correct, please contact us." where contact us should be an hyperlink.

Any idea how to get an working hyperlink into this div?

Kind regards,

Arie

Comment: Use `html()`, not `text()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way to go:

```
if (value.length == '') {
    error_html = 'This is not correct, please <a href="http://domain.com">contact us.</a>';
    $("#div_error").html(error_html);
}
```

Using `.text()`, you force everything to be rendered as text. Use `.html()` instead, so your HTML tags will be parsed.